# Subdomain does not send my forms larger than 3 <input>'s

Tags: php, forms, apache, vps, mt

I have this weird form behaviour on all my subdomains of my server:
I can send and display a form with 1 input field, but when I add mulptiple input's nothing really happens.

I wrote a little test script to get a better understanding of the behaviour. So this is the one that works normally (check out live version [here](http://forum.betacup.be/test/index.php)):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
?>
<html>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<p>Name: <?php f(isset($_POST['submit']))  { echo($_POST['name']); } ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And from the moment that I add some input fields, it does not echo the results (without error reporting) (live version [here](http://forum.betacup.be/test/index2.php)):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Superman: <input type="text" name="superman"><br>
Place: <input type="text" name="place"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<p>Name: <?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))  { echo($_POST['name']); } ?></p>
<p>superman: <?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))  { echo($_POST['superman']); } ?></p>
<p>place: <?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))  { echo($_POST['place']); } ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Same problem occurs when I want to install third party forums like esotalk or FluxBB (I cannot send the installation form). As if the server is just ignoring my forms. This only happens on my subdomains for some bizarre reason..
My server is a (dv) vps hosted at Media Temple. I contacted them 3 times but they couldn't help me. I tried file permissions, compared php.ini settings,... Anyone who might have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

The error it's related to POST size. Try to specify an encoding type to form: enctype="multipart/form-data"